# How to let users add to a long chunk of text without editing the existing text?

Tags: forms

I'm creating a form that generates a description (2-3 sentences) based on the user's choices. I want to allow users to then add more text to the description, but without editing the existing text. Any ideas on how I can do this?

My initial idea was to have a disabled text field with the generated description, and then an "Add to Description" button that creates a new text field below. However, I understand that disabled text fields aren't the best practice, and want to avoid this if possible.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

A segmented input is out of option due to gestalt. 'Add to description' action label is essential to show it as optional so is the second input. So, the best option is to display the first read only message as a multi-line control caption or header while the real input is a multi-line text input control that appears below the label when the user clicks 'Add to description'.

The next problem is the placement of the 'Add to description' button which I think is best positioned below the caption(when the input control is not visible) and of the same width as the label or if lesser in size then right aligned to the label below it. When the user click the button, the button shifts below making space for the text input control.